# Print not working in generator expression

Tags: python, python-3.x

I expect to see a list of combinations of the numbers 1-9, but instead nothing prints.  What am I missing?

```
import itertools

def PrintIt(num):
    print(num)
    return True

nums = itertools.permutations(range(1, 10))

x = (num for num in nums if PrintIt(num)) # Prints nothing
```

If I `print(list(x))`, it prints all the different permutations as expected.

Comment: `x` is a generator you haven't iterated over. You iterate over it when you call `list` on it. What exactly is your question? Did you expect it to print on the line where you assign to `x`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason that is happening is because you are assigning `x` to a generator expression. A generator expression doesn't do any calculation unless needed. To force the calculation the easier way is to force it to be a list. In that situation you are forcing Python to make a list, so python has to perform all the calculations, including testing the if where your print is. So you can make it print this way:

```
x = [num for num in nums if PrintIt(num)]
```

or

```
x = (num for num in nums if PrintIt(num))
list(x)
```

---

By the way, you don't need to have your print function, you could have just done:

```
x = [num for num in nums if print(num)]
```

But using `if` not to test some condition but only for the side effects like you are doing here is debatable at best. That's how i would write your program:

```
import itertools
nums = itertools.permutations(range(1, 10))
for num in nums:
    print(num)
```

Comment: There's nothing mentioned about side effects. That function is returning a boolean value.

Comment: But you don't care about that value really. I sense the OP only put the print on the if as a way to force the expression to be evaluated, not because they were interested on the output of the evaluation but because they were interested  on the side effect (printing on the screen) due to the expression being evaluated. And that's clunky, it's all i'm arguing.

Comment: You do, don't you? That's why it's in the `if`. Say for example if OP's function did more than just printing...